# Use Server.MapPath in jQuery AJAX call while deployed on local IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using WebMethod on my ASPXpage and I call it from jQuery on the same page like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebForm1.aspx/Saveuser",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: parameters,
    dataType: "json",
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

This works fine in my debug environment, but when I deploy on the hosting site it does not. The problem seems to be in the URL because on the server the path would be different. So I used `Server.MapPath` in various ways but none of them worked.

Url: `'<%= Server.MapPath("~/MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData")%>'`

Can anyone overcome this defect?

Comment: If you jQuery code is on the same page you don't need a relative URL. Check the console window, your error seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: No Rahul it well works in visual studio while debugging, it hits the method .But when i hosted in locall  IIS  , website got browsed but when i clicked the button , it didn;t hit the method  and when i checked the console it displayed cannot find WebForm1.aspx/Saveuser

Comment: Okay. But you can't use `Server.MapPath` in JS code, you can use that only in either code behind or mark-up page.

Comment: No, i have used in Javascript in ajax call instead of   url: "WebForm1.aspx/Saveuser", while calling method  i have used  as  Url: '<%= Server.MapPath("~/MyPage.aspx/GetSomeData")%>'